Aiogram does not display the mentioned user in entities
I am developing a telegram bot on aiogram and I ran into a problem: I have a command that accepts the following parameters: the command itself @username (an optional parameter and if it is not present, the sender's id of the message will be used) the name of the item that the user wants to buy. The problem is that I need to get the user id from this @username.
In general, the function looks like this:
@dp.message(Command("buy"))
@UsOper.public
async def buy_item(message: Message):
  try:
    text_words = message.text.split()
    print(message.entities)

    if len(text_words) == 3:
      for entity in message.entities:
        if entity.type == 'mention':
          user_id = entity.user.id
      item_title = text_words[2]

    elif len(text_words) == 2:
      item_title = text_words[1]
      user_id = message.from_user.id
        
    await AssortOper.buy_item(item_title, user_id, message.chat.id)
    await message.reply(f"Item {item_title} purchased!")
except Exception as ex:
    print(ex, "__buy_item")

for some reason, message.entities when mentioning the user = [MessageEntity(type='bot_command', offset=0, length=4, url=None, user=None, language=None, custom_emoji_id=None), MessageEntity(type='mention', offset=5, length=8, url=None, user=None, language=None, custom_emoji_id=None)].
What is the reason for this problem? I seem to be doing everything correctly. (thanks in advance)
I have tried other ways to get the user id using methods of the Bot class, but unfortunately my attempts were unsuccessful
